# objects printing different address after using std::move

Tags: c++

In below code str was moved to s2, thus s2 should be pointing to memory what str was pointing to. Essentially it must have same address. But upon printing they are pointing to different addresses. I am confused if move actually happened.

```
    void test1(std::string&& str) {
      std::string s2 = std::move(str);
      std::cout << &str << std::endl;
      std::cout << &s2 << std::endl;
    }
    
    int main () {
      test1("abc");
    }
```

Comment: The internal pointers in the string may have been moved, but there are two different string objects.

Comment: As 2 independent objects `str` and `s2` always have different addresses. Move operation performed on object content, not on the object themselves.

Comment: `&str` is a pointer to the *object* itself, not the pointer to the internal object. And due to SSO pointer to the internal object may different even if move is performed. You should not rely on this.

Comment: Why do you spam C++ versions in tags? Cannot you decide which version are you using?

Comment: `In below code str was moved to s2, thus s2 should be pointing to memory what str was pointing to.` No this doesn't have to be the case for small strings at all.  Also note that the standard says the moved from object must be in a valid but unspecified state that allows the object to be destructed (and some more details). A move is totally allowed to fallback on copy semantics too (if that's more efficient).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a more interesting test:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void
test1(std::string&& str)
{
    std::cout << (void*)str.data() << '\n';
    std::string s2 = std::move(str);
    std::cout << (void*)s2.data() << '\n';
}

int
main()
{
    test1("abc");
    test1("123456789012345678901234567890");
}
```

This test prints out the address of the data buffer that the string holds its value in.  It is the data buffer, not the string itself, that is transferred during a move.

But it gets more interesting than that for `std::string`.  There are *short* strings and there are *long* strings.  And the definition of short and long differ among implementations.  "Short" strings have their value stored within the `string` itself, as opposed to the `string` pointing to a data buffer.  Whereas the "long" strings point to a heap allocated data buffer (which can be moved).

For me the above test printed out:

```
0x16b9ab5a8
0x16b9ab550
0x600001641200
0x600001641200
```

That is, "abc" is a *short* string.  And when it got moved, there was no heap allocated buffer that changed hands.  Instead one has two stack-allocated buffers, and the "abc" was simply memcpy'd from one to the other with the same efficiency of a copy (which is cheap for 3 `char`).

But "123456789012345678901234567890" is a *long* string which is allocated on the heap.  And when that is moved, ownership of the that allocated buffer is transferred from `str` to `s2`.

The size of the maximum "short string" size varies from platform to platform, and even on a single platform among compiler options.

Answer (score 0):

> str was moved to s2, thus s2 should be pointing to memory what str was pointing to. Essentially it must have same address

No, that is a wrong assumpption/understanding. `s2` and `str` are **two different objects and so(as such) must have distinct addresses.**

The only thing c++ guarantees, is that after the move, the moved from library object will be in a valid but unspecified state.

Answer (score 0):

> In below code `str` was moved to `s2`

As others have pointed out, it was moved before being passed to `s2`'s constructor. Then it was **copied** into s2.

If I re-write the method `test1` to use a const reference rather than making a copy:

```
void test1(std::string&& str)
{
        const auto &str_moved{ std::move(str)};
        std::cout << &str << std::endl;
        std::cout << &str_moved << std::endl;
}
```

The two numbers printed are identical/equal.

If I modify it further:

```
void test1(std::string&& str)
{
        const auto &str_moved{ std::move(str)};
        const auto s2 { str_moved };
        std::cout << "param str:" << &str << " = str_moved: " << &str_moved
                << "; s2: " << &s2 << std::endl;
}
```

then the first 2 pointer addresses are equal but the latter pointer value is different, because the latter is a copy.